# Connect to client FTP with dynamic client IP address

Tags: proxy, ip, ftp

I want to connect to my client's FTP. He has to whitelist my IP everytime since mine is dynamic. How do I connect to his server?

Comment: What is your client's operating system, firewall and ftp server?

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend you to rent a virtual private server (VPS) with static IP and use it as a [jump machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server) to access your client's FTP server from a constant address.

Now there are many particular terminologies each vendor might use, but if it's OK to use Amazon Web Services, then you might be looking for an [EC2](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) nano instance configured with an [Elastic IP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html).

Comment: I am using GCP and have purchased a static IP. If you could tell me what do I set up on my compute engine @uprego

Comment: @MohammedGadiwala If you FTP client supports SOCKS then run `ssh -N -D 127.0.0.1:50000 <username for GCP>@<GCP instance hostname>` on your computer, set your FTP client to use passive mode and use `127.0.0.1:50000` as SOCKS proxy, and you're good to go.

Answer (score 2):

He might use `Port Knocking`. This way, it doesn't matter what IP you have, you'll "knock" to a sequence of ports and the Knock daemon will detect the sequence and therefore add a temporary rule to allow you to connect.

In Linux-based environments you can use `knockd` for that matter, although I'm sure that for other OS environments there are equivalent daemons.

- [More info (knockd)](http://www.zeroflux.org/projects/knock)

Comment: Well the customer wont be doing anything other than whitelisting my one IP address

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to ask him to whitelist your IP each time it changes. You can also get a static IP as @uprego said. No miracles here.

Answer (score 1):

- Setup a free domain name.
- Use OpenDNS to keep the domain name associated with your IP.
- Have your friend whitelist your domain name.