# How to connect to an SSH server externally while protecting my IP address

Tags: linux, ssh, ubuntu-18.04

I can connect to my SSH server externally while using my public IP address, but I would like to try and prevent from telling other people my personal public IP address. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: Every single connection you ever make tells the server you connected to what your IP address is, otherwise it couldn't reply to you. Why the concern over this one single instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually multiple options here.

The most generalized is to use a vpn. The advantages there is that it can also be used to mask your actual IP in other applications and can provide near total anonymity. The disadvantages include it not being free, as a rule, and often still leaving you with a single, different ip (the ip of the vpn gateway) which can be targeted.

Another option is to use ssh forwarding. This lets you connect to one ssh server which then fowards your connection to another ssh server. The final destination ssh server only sees the ip of the ssh server in the middle. Advantages and disadvantages are essentially the same as using a vpn, plus the vpn is usually easier to setup and vpn providers are more common.

Probably the best free option is to use an anonymizing proxy network... like Tor. There's usually a pretty hefty performance cost with the the free options but ssh is not particularly bandwidth intensive (unless you are doing file transfers). Another problem is that some servers will block "exit servers" (the ip the destination sees) because of abuse issues common to such networks. But one unique advantage is that your apparent ip will change often as your connection is routed and rerouted by the anonymizing network.

Answer (score 0):

You can rent a virtual private server (VPS) and use it as a [jump machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jump_server) to access the SSH server.

Now there are many particular terminologies each vendor might use, but if it's OK to use Amazon Web Services, then you might be looking for an [EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) nano instance.

Adapted from another previous answer of mine: https://superuser.com/a/1462580/174140. Beware dragons.